# Reinstall Safari version 5

Tags: safari, leopard

Apologies in advance if any of the details seem incorrect, I am helping my friends dad and am not a mac user myself.

Background to problem:

His System: Mac OS X v10.5.8

Original Browser: Safari v5

Recently he has been unable to access some websites and was informed by one company that he needed to update his browser.

He downloaded Safari v7.0.4 to find that it could not be used with leopard.

to quote

> The main problem is, that in the process of downloading v7, v5 was deleted & now I have no access to any website.
>
> I have dumped v7 to 'trash' but still cannot retrieve v5.

I checked the compatibility and it looks like he needs to go back to Safari 5.0.6 (I'll worry about OS update later)

Whats are my options to get Safari 5 working again on his machine?

Also is there any way for me to remote to his machine without him having a browser?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: It time to upgrade the OS or the computer as Mac OS X Lion is no longer supported and has unresolved security issues. Restoring Safari 5 won't resolve the issue of not working with sites that will reject it.

Comment: Agree it needs an OS update, I'm waiting on the spec to see what it can be updated to but for now just need to get Safari 5 working.

Comment: It's bizarre to me that he was able to even run the Safari 7 installer, as it clearly is not supported by his OS...

Answer (score 1):

With you not having a Mac and with him having such an old OS, you probably aren't going to be able to remote in.

That said, even without a browser he should still be able to download Safari v5.0.6 which is the latest version supported by his OS.

Type the following commands into Terminal exactly as they appear, pressing Return after each one, and he should end up with Safari in his Downloads folder.

```
cd ~/Downloads
curl -O http://supportdownload.apple.com/download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Apple_Software_Updates/Mac_OS_X/downloads/041-5122.20110720.2HQcx/Safari5.0.6Leopard.dmg
```

(That's a capital O in the `curl` command.) It reports its size as 52.2 MB.

There is one big caveat, though - depending on what the Safari v7 installer did to his system, it may not work to reinstall v5, in which case he may need to reinstall the OS.

Comment: That URL no longer works

Comment: Given that the current release is Safari 14, and at the time of my post Safari 5 was already about six years old, it is hardly surprising to find out that the link is now dead.